# How to automatically add argument names to a method call in C# and Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I like the named arguments feature of C# 4.0, I noticed that in some circumstances it greatly improves the readability of my code. Is there a refactoring extension to VS, which would convert a normal method call to a call with explicit argument names? Like this:

Before:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Foo", "Bar");
```

After:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName: "Foo", value: "Bar");
```

Comment: CodeRush doesn't have that feature, but I've trying to get them to add it to the next version.

Comment: I have been nagging on Resharper team too.